# Vuejs webpack still shows older js versions in firefox and chrome's debugger

Tags: vue.js, webpack

My vuejs application runs substantially slower in Firefox, but lot faster in Chrome. This is how I create the vuejs build. I always change the version number of the package. Based on that, it creates the js folder as well as the package version. However, in the Firefox debugger, older versions of the js files in webpack are still displayed. The screenshot is attached.

[image]

Here is vue.config.js file content.

```
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      config.output.filename = `js_${process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION}/[name].[contenthash:8].min.js`
      config.output.chunkFilename = `js_${process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION}/[name].[contenthash:8].min.js`
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev") {
      config.output.filename = `js_dev_${process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION}/[name].[contenthash:6].min.js`
      config.output.chunkFilename = `js_dev_${process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION}/[name].[contenthash:6].min.js`
    } else {
      config.output.filename = 'js/[name].js'
      config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/[name].js';
    }
  },
};
```

How can I get rid of the duplicate js_10.0.6 and so on from webpack? Is this why it runs so slowly on Firefox and Chrome and sometimes becomes unresponsive?